# Jquery hide image after rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, hide

I have an image that rotates 360 on a click event. After the image is done rotating, I would like that image to disappear. Any suggestions?

```
$("#refresh").rotate({
   bind:
     {
        click: function(){
            $(this).rotate({ angle:0,animateTo:720,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo });
            $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        }
     }

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="span4" style="float:right">

    <img src="assets/img/refresh_btn.png" id="refresh" width="70" height="70"/> 

</div>
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I do not want to use the fadeout function, just have it spin and then hide. thanks!

Comment: Is `jQuery.fn.rotate` some plugin that you have or just pseudo-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using this? http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Documentation

In that case use the callback that's fired upon completion. Something like this:

```
$("#refresh").rotate({
   bind:
     {
        click: function(){
            $(this).rotate({ angle:0,animateTo:720,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo });
            $(this).fadeOut("slow");
        },
        callback: function(){
            $(this).hide();
        },
     }

});
```

Comment: thanks Jacob! worked for me with a little tweaking! Should have thought of that one myself!